What could be the reason for openmp to constantly recreate the thread pool?
My program runs on linux, and uses a openmp-enabled dynamic library (named calc.so) for fast parallel computation, calc.so exports this function double calc(double* data).
When the program is running, I used command strace -p {prog_pid} and found the the running process is constantly creating a thread pool (I see a lot clone,futex syscalls).
I only have very limited openmp experience, I remember openmp thread pool is created only once. How come this time the thread pool is created over and over again? Is it related the use openmp in dynamic library? Anyone can give me a clue? Thanks.

Whether threads are reused or not is implementation specific behavior. It also depends on various other factors. So, which openmp do you use? Probably try another Compiler and see whether the behavior works better for you. Llvm openmp, for example, reuses threads for the first level of parallelism but respawns threads for nested parallel regions.

I use gcc 8.5.0. I have tried simple openmp example found from internet, it does reused the threadpool.  The so lib is provided by another team.

I agree that this is dependent of various factors. One of them is that you set the number of thread manually. The chance for the thread not to be recycled increase even more when this number change from one iteration to another. If you mix multiple OpenMP implementation, the same thing can happen. This typically happen with multiple compilers or possibly even different version of the same compiler. You should try to use the same compiler tool-chain for the whole build if possible (including the link step). SO files does not help either because they can be loaded/unloaded at any time.
